# Typescript doesn't understand infer type when dealing with a generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null;

const sayHelloTo = (str: string) => console.log(`hello ${str}`);

function myFunc( x: string[] ) {
    x.forEach(item => sayHelloTo(item))
}

const x = ['abc', null, 'xyz'] as Maybe<string>[];
const newX = x.filter(item => item !== null);

// Error: newX still type Maybe<string>[] does not match the expected <string>[]
myFunc(newX);
```

Am I wrong to expect Typescript to be smart enough to deal with this or did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error [in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4AoGgYwHtiBnYKFhACQksbUY4oACjYAnAFwdgYgJbEA5gEocWAAYALXuUEASAN7iAvmto0AZqWL1gs5lAC2IAGJX6wqAA8p8JKnHyClgq+nRQ4VCy5iKeITQRCRzc2vyMwrFUUAD0WXjgECz0cmDsTA5g5HDyLFJo+VAA5GSUDZEsJIzscCwssgrEcIjk0MCCoJDScorxEUZhEVExUACE2LjN5HGJEZwgPHwC6UqZOXmQhcXsbLKUUGUVVay19U0U5K2y7cSdUN29-YNhlBRsD6gFpgk5kYgA)

Comment: @LindaPaiste you are absolutely correct. I am not seeing that error in the playground example or [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4AoGgYwHtiBnYKFhACQksbUY4oACjYAnAFwdgYgJbEA5gEocWJq0bkIAOnKMFwgAYALXnqgASAN7iAvoaW0aAM1LF6wWcygBbEADE3emEoAA8peCRUcXkFLBUrGihkqFlnEVCEpJSczhAePgFhTKooAHoyvHAIFno5MHYmHzByOHkWKTRqqAByMkoe1JYSRnY4FhZZBWI4RC0oYEFQSGk5RWzk2zoctIyoAEJsXH7yLJzc7jN+RmLHcsquyFr69jZZSigmlrbWTu6+ijkQayYbEUZQcaTaazeaLBbdGLrHJbLYMZhsMJCHqzeiDcawBDIFCIuJOPyBdy3KhAA)

Comment: @LindaPaiste I over simplified the issue and didn't properly capture the issue. I've updated the sample and shows the error now in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4AoGgYwHtiBnYKFhACQksbUY4oACjYAnAFwdgYgJbEA5gEocWJq0bkIAOnKMFwgAYALXnqgASAN7iAvoaW0aAM1LF6wWcygBbEADE3emEoAA8pcXkFAG0AXSgVKxooFLDtZ0YxAFE4emNhWWAIH1UObjN+RgKinyUlGls6dTYwoWiAcjhEenaAGhIKcn720JAAL3b4uBZYBGQUSMUMONpm9mIIAHcADSFQ9NlyIrFq4tLCs4BCbFwySkc6AHpHqCyxMUypDZ3pQ-IoUCQWZIVCLBTLeIAE0YEBmxEY7B8cGAeQBpigEFCkA8EEhUAWMiiEJofkC7mE322DyAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript isn't able to infer that `x.filter(item => item !== null)` filters out `null` values.

When I've hit this in the past, I've explicitly set defined the type. Example:

```
const newX = x.filter(item => item !== null) as string[];
```

It would be great if TypeScript could infer this automatically, but as it stands, I think explicitly setting the type is the easiest way forward.

Comment: That's a shame. We are trying to remove all `as` type coercions from our app. I guess if this is the case it makes sense to keep it in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type guard for this!

```js
const x : Maybe<string>[] = ['abc', null, 'xyz'];
const newX = x.filter((i) : i is string => i !== null);
// newX is now known to be a string[]
```

The `i is string` return guard indicates that a truthy return value from this function indicates that the object passed in was a string. This lets Typescript figure out that the result of the filter is going to be a `string[]`, because all items for which the predicate passes are claimed to satisfy `is string`.

You can put this into a reusable form with something like this:

```
function notNull<T>(
  value: Maybe<T>
): value is T {
  return value !== null;
}

// ...
const newX = x.filter(notNull);
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4AoGgM1OIGNgBLAe2JI+ADkK5dADU45UhAwAKGlCgA3MRIBcsBMhFLJNAJSrF46GwDOeUYagBvWVABOEYKVvcDEqAEJsuMpVoBfOmYuY2AoYwQACQhKDjQOHCgpENtVZLZiAHMdHCwg4mMOcggAOnIODKkAAwALaLKoABJLZL9KnVoGJlZObgBbEAAxLqkoAA9U4Ft0jIBtAF0obOs5OVHi+g5bAFE4ZmqpNmAIXpywyLrYjgOj3p0dGgCaPJCxqFV4JFQ0zIx5hJmAORwRDMAEAGhIgghANGIAAXgC5h1nqFiBAAO4ADQSa3obHIR1sUgO2VUbCgJjCk2mp3Jnm8gnaNH6QxYUjRWKZT2CqIxmIATDj1vjCezeAJKEyWcMOQKmUA) demonstrating the technique.

Answer (score 1):

As @Soc said, the issue is with typescript not understand what is being filtered out in `Array.prototype.filter`.

The good news is that you can get a proper type for a filtered array by using a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
const isNotNull = <T extends any>(value: T): value is Exclude<T, null> => {
    return value !== null;
}
```

Our guard function is very simple.  We declare that if `value !== null` then the type of the value `T` should not include `null`.

When we use this type guard as our filter function, the returned array is of type `string[]` and there is no problem calling `myFunc(newX)`.

```
const newX = x.filter(isNotNull); // has type string[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4AoGgYwHtiBnYKFhACQksbUY4oACjYAnAFwdgYgJbEA5gEocWJq0bkIAOnKMFwgAYALXnqgASAN7iAvoaW0aAM1LF6wWcygBbEADE3emEoAA8pcXkFAG0AXSgVKxooFLDtZ0YxAFE4emNhWWAIH1UObjN%20RgKinyUlGls6dTYwoWiAcjhEenaAGhIKcn720JAAL3b4uBZYBGQUSMUMOKdm9lkWADlGYE3BoXQoCFCi4gATGbhiEAxhADc4clIIKTQlKQen6A2oLND6J5nVBofpkShYbBYJKpKBiCDAUhiYhQT7PKAAQmwuDB1AaTWYLWIEAA7gANIShdKychFMQFLY7PaURx0PyBdzCIlkllAA)

`item !== null` works as a type guard for most purposes, but for whatever reason it doesn't work inside of `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the type definition of `filter` is a follows:

`filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];`

Where `T` in your case is still `Maybe<string>`. Therefore you need to explicitly declare the type of `newX`.